# Passing string vs. passing integer to JavaScript function as good practice?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Let say I have a JavaScript function and I want to use it as number to calculate.

However, I could either pass in string number (then convert to integer) or integer directly. Which one is good practice, considering that I'm writing plugging for other users to use and they have no knowledge of implementation detail (of course I could read function signature to see which one to pass in).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling all conversions within the function body allows for greater flexibility. A function is supposed to do stuff for you, not require you to do stuff.

Converting from string to integer isn't difficult, and you could throw an exception if the string passed is unparseable to prevent silent failure.

Answer (score 2):

Use whatever is apropriate for the situation.  If you are writing a function to add two numbers, expect an input of a number not a string.  You can always choose to deal with the situation where someone passes a string however to prevent failure.

**Documentation** is the key to 3rd party plugins.  This will let your users know what they should be passing in, what functions are available and how to use them.